# Doubtful predictions of Neural Network implemented in C++

Tags: c++, machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation, feed-forward

I have created a Neural Network in C++ for approximating addition function **y = x + y**. I used a single hidden layer with 5 neurons. The values of x and y lie in the range 0 and 10. So before training, I normalized the training data(input as well as output data) by the Maximum value (2x10).

After my model makes the prediction (lying between 0 & 1), I de-normalize the prediction by multiplying it with 2x20. But, my result still shows a shift.

i.e, if the result (y) should have been predicted as 8, my network gives -12. And similarly, instead of 1, I get -19. To correct this shift, I added 20 to my predicted value. This is what I get:
[image: ignore the title, *f(x)= sin(x)*]

*ignore the title, f(x)= sin(x), where, **Blue** shows the actual result and **Red** shows predicted value(after I add 20 manually)*

My question is: Is my network predicting well ?  And is "adding 20 manually to the result" normal?

*(P.S: [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1237026/Simple-MLP-Backpropagation-Artificial-Neural-Netwo) to reference code, and  [Link](https://github.com/PrashantDandriyal/Neural-Networks-In-Cpp/blob/master/2Input_1Output_Addition.cpp) to my problematic code)*

Comment: So have you tried to debug your program at all? Are you sure it implements the algorithm correctly?

Comment: I am doubtful of the way I update the weights of the synapse between hidden layer and output layer. Though, I can't figure out the wrong doing.

Comment: Step through your program with a debugger and watch the variables. Compare the state of the variables to what you expect, by e.g. performing the algorithm on paper. You can also try a much simpler case first, e.g. predicting a constant function with only one hidden node, etc. This way you will find out whether and where your program implements the algorithm wrong or why the network finds a suboptimal solution.

Comment: Will try that tommorow morning and reply asap. :)

Comment: You should be calculating training and validation MSE (mean squared error) and plot versus iteration # or epoch #, as in conventional ML literature. That way you will see how your overall error evolves during the training process and will hint you if the algorithm is correct